# Erro que esta ocorrendo

Tags: c#

```
<td>
  @Html.ActionLink("Editar","EditarPessoa", new { cod=item.Id }) |
  @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Detalhes", new { cod=item.Id }) |
  @Html.ActionLink("Deletar","DeletarPessoa", new { cod=item.Id })
</td>
```

---

```
public ActionResult EditarPessoa(int id)
{
  var pessoaOBJ = pessoaNegocio.BuscarPessoa(id);
  var pessoaVM = ModelParaModel(pessoaOBJ);
  return View(pessoaVM);
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditarPessoa(ViewModelPessoa modelPessoa)
{
  pessoaNegocio.Alterar(ViewModelParaModel(modelPessoa));
  return View("ListarPessoa","Pessoa");
}

public ActionResult DeletarPessoa(int id)
{
  var pessoaOBJ = pessoaNegocio.BuscarPessoa(id);
  var pessoaVM = ModelParaModel(pessoaOBJ);
  return View(pessoaVM);
}

[HttpDelete]
public ActionResult DeletarPessoa(ViewModelPessoa modelPessoa)
{
  var pessoa = ViewModelParaModel(modelPessoa);
  pessoaNegocio.Deletar(pessoa.Id);
  return View();
}
```

quando clica no botão excluir e editar da o seguinte erro:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult EditarPessoa(Int32)' in 'ProjetoDadosPessoa.Controllers.PessoaController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Nome do parâmetro: parameters

---

Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'.

> The number of primary key values passed must match number of primary key values defined on the entity.
>   Nome do parâmetro: keyValues
>   Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código.

Detalhes da Exceção:

> System.ArgumentException: The number of primary key values passed must match number of primary key values defined on the entity.
>   Nome do parâmetro: keyValues

Erro de Origem:

```
Linha 34:         public T Buscar(params object[] Key)
Linha 35:         {
Linha 36:             return _db.Set<T>().Find(Key);
Linha 37:         }
Linha 38:
```

Arquivo de Origem:

> C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Projetos_CSharp\projetos_estudados\ProjetoDadosPessoa\ProjetoDadosPessoa.DAL\Repositorio\GenericRepositorio.cs    Linha: 36

Rastreamento de Pilha:

```
[ArgumentException: The number of primary key values passed must match number of primary key values defined on the entity.
Nome do parâmetro: keyValues]
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.WrappedEntityKey..ctor(EntitySet entitySet, String entitySetName, Object[] keyValues, String keyValuesParamName) +429
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Find(Object[] keyValues) +121
   System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Find(Object[] keyValues) +29
   ProjetoDadosPessoa.DAL.Repositorio.GenericRepositorio`1.Buscar(Object[] Key) in C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Projetos_CSharp\projetos_estudados\ProjetoDadosPessoa\ProjetoDadosPessoa.DAL\Repositorio\GenericRepositorio.cs:36
   ProjetoDadosPessoa.Negocio.Negocio.PessoaNegocio.BuscarPessoa(Int32 id) in C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Projetos_CSharp\projetos_estudados\ProjetoDadosPessoa\ProjetoDadosPessoa.Negocio\Negocio\PessoaNegocio.cs:42
   ProjetoDadosPessoa.Controllers.PessoaController.DeletarPessoa(Int32 id) in C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Projetos_CSharp\projetos_estudados\ProjetoDadosPessoa\ProjetoDadosPessoa\Controllers\PessoaController.cs:47
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +96
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__9_0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__11_0() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__3() +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9748493
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +159

Informações sobre a Versão: Microsoft .NET Framework Versão:4.0.30319; Versão do ASP.NET:4.7.2558.0


da esse erro aqui


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ProjetoDadosPessoa.DAL.Repositorio.Interface;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using ProjetoDadosPessoa.DAL.Contexto;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace ProjetoDadosPessoa.DAL.Repositorio
{
    public class GenericRepositorio<T> : IGenericRepositorio<T>, IDisposable where T : class
    {
        private readonly ProjetoDadosPessoaContexto _db;

        public GenericRepositorio()
        {
            _db = new ProjetoDadosPessoaContexto();
        }

        public void Adicionar(T entidade)
        {
            _db.Set<T>().Add(entidade);
            Commit();
        }

        public void Atualizar(T entidade)
        {
            _db.Entry(entidade).State = EntityState.Modified;
            Commit();
        }

        public T Buscar(params object[] Key)
        {
            return _db.Set<T>().Find(Key);
        }

        public void Commit()
        {
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Deletar(int i)
        {
            var obj = Buscar(i);
            _db.Set<T>().Remove(obj);
            Commit();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if(_db != null)
            {
                _db.Dispose();
            }

            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        public List<T> Obter(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return _db.Set<T>().Where(predicate).ToList();
        }

        public List<T> ObterTodos()
        {
            return _db.Set<T>().ToList();
        }

        public T Primeiro(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return _db.Set<T>().Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sua view não deve estar com `id` preenchida, ou ela nem existe lá

Comment: O que é `cod`, vey? Troca `cod` pra `id`

Answer (score 1):

Pelo o que posso ver no seu trecho de código, você recebe no seu método o parametro int id, mas no seu código você passa cod. Isso faz com que o parametro não seja reconhecido.

Você não mostrou o código dos Detalhes, mas irei fazer para ele da mesma forma que fiz para os outros.

Tente fazer o seguinte:

```
<td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Editar","EditarPessoa", new { id = item.Id }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Detalhes", new { id = item.Id }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Deletar","DeletarPessoa", new { id = item.Id })
</td>
```